# -bash process suddenly taking 75% CPU in htop

Tags: terminal, bash

When I open a terminal and run htop I am seeing a `-bash` process that is taking up 75% of my CPU. I am not running any scripts or anything like that. I constantly have 3-4 terminals open and I have never seen this happen before. I tried to kill the process but it doesn't go away.

What should I try next?

Comment: How did you try to kill it? Does `ps -p <pid>` give any clues about where the process might come from? Does quitting/restarting Terminal help?

Comment: quitting restarting terminal does not help, no idea where it came from I did an `F9` sigterm. `ps -p` gives this `9032 ttys001  381:06.57 -bash`

Comment: If `kill -9 9032` doesn't help, it's probably time for a reboot

Comment: that seems to have worked, I always end up thinking that htop kills are as powerfull as the kill command...Any idea "in theory" what this is? Is this a zombie process?

Comment: strangely enough I started seeing this error sometimes when I open a new bash terminal...`-bash: .launchctl_auto_complete.bash: No such file or directory`

Comment: Maybe something gets "stuck" by that.

Comment: I have the same problem (on a raspberry) with bash and sudo taking up 100% and 65% of CPU while I am just logged in with one ssh connection and one terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most run-away processes can be killed with `kill -9 PID`. Any unsaved data kept by the process will be lost.